# Is there a way to determine which applications are covered by a company's security policy?

Tags: group-policy, security-policy

I've connected my personal laptop to my work account and they have a security policy in place.  Under "Applications" it's a list of guids that I want to link to an actual application name.  Is there a way to find which application is represented by each GUID?

> •{{9c45b7b6-7469-45fc-a4f0-0483bc4948fa}}: EnforcementCompleted

Above is an example of a list item under "applications"

Comment: You might have to search the Registry for each GUID... or ask your IT department, who might take a dim view on such a saerch.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks

Comment: I'm surprised you are allowed to do this. It would be instant dismissal if I attached a personal laptop to my company network.

Comment: @DavidPostill you're confusing two different things.  This is a security policy in place to allow me to install programs like teams or outlook.  I'm not on the company network. There's a sandbox environment for that.